# Geocode API does not recognize address, although google maps does

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocode

I am using Geocode API on a project, where users have a text input to enter an address. This address is found using Google Maps API, however, Geocode API cannot find the address. The strange part is that it works for some addresses, but for some others it doesn't.

For example, the address *Courchevel, Saint-Bon-Tarentaise, France* can be found on Google Maps, but not with the Geocode URL: *https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Courchevel%2C%20Saint-Bon-Tarentaise%2C%20France&sensor=false&client=gme-kickzag&signature=MY_SIGNATURE=*, where MY_SIGNATURE is given correctly.

On the other hand, the address *Basel, Switzerland* works correctly: https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Basel%2C%20Switzerland&sensor=false&client=gme-kickzag&signature=MY_SIGNATURE=

Any answer is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Places Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details) and pass it a place ID. Only catch is you have to pass the service an instance of a map or an html element node. Here's an example:

```
// "map" is a google map you have created
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

var request = {
  placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
};

service.getDetails(request, callback);

function callback(place, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    var lat = results.geometry.location.lat(),
        long = results.geometry.location.lng();
    console.log('lat & long', lat, long);
  }
}
```

In my case since I am not using a map so I passed it an html node like

```
var details = document.getElementById('details');
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(details);
```

To adhere to the terms, you cannot hide the element. However it appears the service doesn't augment it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the problem seems to be with the Geocode itself. With what I could understand from some research, Geocode sometimes has difficulties on translating addresses to longitude and latitude.

Comment: @Shend you ought to use the autocomplete service for the user input. It's super easy. You can have it render the UI for you, or just return results so you can handle the UI part. Then you have a placeId, which will guarantee you lat/long.

Answer (score 0):

The subject of searching for addresses is complex. Some things that are difficult include:

- knowing how to [parse an address](https://smartystreets.com/articles/does-google-parse-standardize)
- making sure [an address is real](https://smartystreets.com/articles/do-maps-verify-addresses)
- understanding [what a user means](https://searchenginewatch.com/2016/04/12/everything-you-need-to-know-about-natural-language-search-2/) by their search
- giving an appropriate [result for partial address](https://smartystreets.com/articles/autocomplete)
- providing [geocode information](https://smartystreets.com/articles/what-are-geocodes) matching an address

There is a lot of useful information about addresses and searching in the [FAQ articles](https://smartystreets.com/articles) from SmartyStreets.

As for your question, you have brought up an interesting case. (It is not quite clear what your question is, but on the theme of Google APIs...) Google has many products, which were created to solve specific problems. In one case, it might be good for Google to help users explore an area: they want to find a region and show restaurants and events, etc. In a different case, it would be good for Google to find an exact geocode location. Thus, it is important for Google API users to think through their problem and goals, and make a correct decision about which tools to use. You might find the [Google API Picker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker) to be useful.

Fair disclosure: I work for [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com), a company which focuses on address validation.